# Pasar JSON de node js a html con AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, json, nodejs

Quiero pasar datos de una función de node js a una plantilla de html.

La plantilla es html plano, donde el tengo que pasar la versión del programa que viene dado por un JSON tomado con nodejs.

La función nodejs es la siguiente:

```
app.post('/get-version', (req, res) => {
        res.json(get-version());
    });
```

Estoy medio perdido para hacer la llamada desde el html a esa función y poder insertar el dato en un título:

```
<h1>Programa <small>V 1.1.0</small></h1>
```

En lugar de 1.1.0, debería ir la versión del programa, el cuál se devuelve en un JSON de la siguiente manera:

```
}
     "version": "2.3.4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea realizar una llamada Ajax a un método de un servidor NodeJS. El resultado debe mostrarse en un elemento del documento `html` que hace la llamada.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Existen muchas formas de hacerlo, lo que necesitas es implementar alguna de tantas. Por ejemplo, podrías usar la API [`Fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch).

Pero el primer detalle que voy a intentar corregir en tu método es que el mismo está escrito usando el verbo [`POST`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST):

```
app.post('/get-version', (req, res) => {
    res.json(get-version());
});
```

Si bien, esto podría funcionar, es anti natural ya que el propósito de la misma `url` implicada en este método no es recibir datos para crear un nuevo recurso (ver [CRUD](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD)), sino al contrario, solicitar un recurso.

Entonces, lo más adecuado sería usar un método del tipo [`GET`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET).

También, podemos hacer un cambio en la `url`, ya que la misma debería representar la entidad a la que estamos haciendo referencia y no la acción sobre la misma. La acción la expresamos mediante uno de los verbos: `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc.

Mi propuesta es que uses el siguiente método en tu aplicación:

```
app.get('/version', (req, res) => {
    res.json(get-version());
});
```

Así, seremos consistentes con el método y el recurso solicitado.

Por último, sin saber exactamente dónde se ejecuta tu aplicación y si la misma está configurada en un puerto específico (distinto del puerto 80 para `http` o 443 para `https`), debemos tener a mano la `URI` correcta para consumir el recurso representado por `/version`.

Supongamos que tienes tu aplicación `Express` (NodeJS) en el puerto típico: 3000. Por lo tanto el acceso a la raíz de la misma sería: `http://localhost:3000`. Así, si deseamos la versión de la aplicación, que se resuelve mediante la ruta `/version`, tenemos que la `URI` a consumir sería: `http://localhost:3000/version`.

Una forma en que puedes mostrar la información devuelta por dicha ruta sería mediante la siguiente llamada [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Primeros_Pasos) usando la API Fecth:

```js
let URI = 'http://localhost:3000/version'
fetch(URI)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    document.getElementById('version').innerText(json.version);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(`Error al intentar la solicitud: ${error.message}`);
    document.getElementById('version').innerText(undefined);
  });
```

Para que esto funcione puedes hacer dos cosas: usar un botón para que la acción se ejecute a petición del usuario o hacer la solicitud apenas se cargue el contenido de la página web. Para ello, el `script` debes colocarlo al final de tu documento `html` justo antes del cierre de la etiqueta `</body>`. También es importante recalcar que debemos identificar el elemento que deseamos reciba el valor de nuestra respuesta. En este caso hemos establecido un atributo `id` sobre el elemento: `<small id="version"></small>`

Por ejemplo:

```html
<body>
<h1>Programa <small id="version"></small></h1>
<script>
let URI = 'http://localhost:3000/version'
fetch(URI)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    document.getElementById('version').innerText = json.version;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(`Error al intentar la solicitud: ${error.message}`);
    document.getElementById('version').innerText = undefined;
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Un ejemplo de esto, usando la API de [`randomuser.me`](https://randomuser.me/), sería el siguiente:

```html
<body>
<h1>Programa <small id="version"></small></h1>
<script>
let URI = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=gender,name,nat&nat=ES';
fetch(URI)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    
 let version = json.info.version;   document.getElementById('version').innerText = `V ${version}`;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    console.log(`Error al intentar la solicitud: ${error.message}`);
    document.getElementById('version').innerText = '<Valor por defecto>';
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Un ejemplo de la respuesta de la llamada la API de `randomuser.me` es la siguiente:

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "gender": "male",
      "name": {
        "title": "Mr",
        "first": "Marc",
        "last": "Ferrer"
      },
      "nat":"ES"
    }
  ],
  "info": {
    "seed": "e92f4d9ca8229707",
    "results": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "version": "1.3"
  }
}
```

De allí que saquemos el valor de la versión del programa usando:

```
json.info.version
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema y deje un poco más claros ciertos conceptos.